# iTunes Connect can't register new bundle ID

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When adding an app through iTunes Connect, I am unable to register a new bundle ID. I am taken to https://developer.apple.com/iphone/my/bundles/index.action, which shows a 404 error. I am assuming that this is a lingering issue caused by Apple not being entirely done fixing its developer site, but I felt there might be a chance that it was just me having this issue.

Can someone confirm that the register new bundle ID function of iTunesConnect is still unavailable? Or, if it is available, how might I regain access to it?

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/ iTC is up. I haven't tried making a new ID myself though.

Comment: Itc is up but not all functions are operational. Try contacting the developer site and ask them if that function is available yet.

Comment: I successfully sent an app to iTC during server downtime. The problem is that since they restarted the server "certificate, device & profiles" section was totally reset. Can't see my appID, certificates, devices, anymore

Comment: just got to - http://devimages.apple.com/maintenance/ then select **status page**. In service section select first column first row **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles** now you are able to login to your developer account. I think this is what u r asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered a workaround.

The link for creating a new bundle id is broken in the dialogue for adding a new app to iTunes connect, but adding id's can be accessed also through the certificates, identifiers, and profiles section of the developer site.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it via the Certficates, Identifiers and Profiles section. If you are logged in, this should take you straight there :)

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action

Comment: Yes, this is the correct link. It would be nice if apple would update iTunes Connect to lead you their instead of the 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Just to say, I have the exact same problem. Just get a 404 when I try to get a new BundleID in ITC.
I'm not sure what we are supposed to do at the moment.